# Magento2 Complete path is not showing in breadcrumbs on product detail page

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.3

If I open category,subcategory and vertical the breadcrumbs that are showing properly

For reference please find the attached image.

[image]

If I open product from home page then breadcrumbs are not showing complete path. It is showing only Home and product name

For reference please find the attached image.
[image]

I need complete path like

> Home -> Category -> Subcategory -> Vetical -> product name

How can I get this one ?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you enter the product page via search or via the product listing page/category page?

Comment: via product listing page/category page

Comment: Using any external service to serve category page ? Vanilla Magento shows the breadcrumb coming from the category page. Out of the box from whatever category a user comes the breadcrumb is shown, except if you have a custom theme which changes this.

Comment: I got solution from this link
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/295742/breadcumbs-are-not-coming-properly

Answer (score 0):

You need to customize your breadcrumb, it will work even if you open product from home page

First you have to add block in your module

**Path**: `app\code\Vendor\Module\Block\Crumbblock.php`

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use Magento\Store\Model\Store;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;

class Crumbblock extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

    /**
     * Catalog data
     *
     * @var Data
     */
    protected $_catalogData = null;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Data $catalogData
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context, 
        Data $catalogData, 
        Registry $registry,
        array $data = [])
    {
        $this->_catalogData = $catalogData; 
        $this->registry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getCrumbs()
    {
        $evercrumbs = array();

        $evercrumbs[] = array(
            'label' => 'Home',
            'title' => 'Go to Home Page',
            'link' => $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl()
        );

        $path = $this->_catalogData->getBreadcrumbPath();
        $product = $this->registry->registry('current_product');
        $categoryCollection = clone $product->getCategoryCollection();
        $categoryCollection->clear();
        $categoryCollection->addAttributeToSort('level', $categoryCollection::SORT_ORDER_DESC)->addAttributeToFilter('path', array('like' => "1/" . $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getRootCategoryId() . "/%"));
        $categoryCollection->setPageSize(1);
        $breadcrumbCategories = $categoryCollection->getFirstItem()->getParentCategories();
        foreach ($breadcrumbCategories as $category) {
            $evercrumbs[] = array(
                'label' => $category->getName(),
                'title' => $category->getName(),
                'link' => $category->getUrl()
            );
        }


        $evercrumbs[] = array(
                'label' => $product->getName(),
                'title' => $product->getName(),
                'link' => ''
            );

        return $evercrumbs;
    }
}
```

After that add layout file `catalog_product_view.xml` in your module
**Path should be**: `app\code\Vendor\Module\view\frontend\layout\catalog_product_view.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page>
    <body>
    <referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs" remove="true" />
    <referenceContainer name="page.top">
        <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Crumbblock" name="crumbs" as="crumbs" template="Vendor_Module::crumbs.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

After that Add phtml file in your module
Path Should be like: `app\code\Vendor\Module\view\frontend\templates\crumbs.phtml`

```
<?php $crumbs = $block->getCrumbs(); ?>
<?php if ($crumbs && is_array($crumbs)) : ?>
<div class="container">
    <div class="breadcrumbs">
        <ul class="items">
            <?php
            foreach ($crumbs as $crumbName => $crumbInfo) : ?>
                <li class="item <?php echo $crumbName == 0 ? "home" : ""; ?>">
                    <?php if ($crumbInfo['link']) : ?>
                        <a href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */
                        $crumbInfo['link'] ?>" title="<?= $block->escapeHtml($crumbInfo['title']) ?>">
                            <?= $block->escapeHtml($crumbInfo['label']) ?>
                        </a>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <strong><?= $block->escapeHtml($crumbInfo['label']) ?></strong>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </li>
            <?php
            endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**I hope this will help**

Answer (score 0):

there is a few variants to get BreadCrumbs from the box in Magento

1. If product has category path in URL
2. Referer ( config )

Magento ver. 2.4.5

but I find diper category and get Path from there

required

1. Plugin for Magento\Catalog\ViewModel\Product\Breadcrumbs

file Vendor\Module\Plugin\ViewModel\Product\Breadcrumbs

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\ViewModel\Product;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductLinkRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Escaper;
use Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\JsonHexTag;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Session as CatalogSession;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager;

class Breadcrumbs
{
    protected $registry;
    /**
     * @var Escaper
     */
    protected $escaper;
    /**
     * @var JsonHexTag
     */
    protected $jsonSerializer;
    /**
     * @var CatalogSession
     */
    private $catalogSession;

    /**
     * @var ProductRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $productRepository;

    /**
     * Current Product
     *
     * @var ProductInterface
     */
    private $currentProduct;
    /**
     * @var StoreManager
     */
    protected $storeManager;
    /**
     * @var ProductLinkRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $productLinkRepository;

    /**
     * @param CatalogSession $catalogSession
     * @param ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
     * @param Escaper $escaper
     * @param JsonHexTag $jsonSerializer
     * @param ProductLinkRepositoryInterface $productLinkRepository
     * @param StoreManager $storeManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        CatalogSession $catalogSession,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        Escaper $escaper,
        JsonHexTag $jsonSerializer,
        ProductLinkRepositoryInterface $productLinkRepository,
        StoreManager $storeManager
    ) {
        $this->catalogSession = $catalogSession;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->escaper = $escaper;
        $this->jsonSerializer = $jsonSerializer;
        $this->productLinkRepository = $productLinkRepository;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    /**
     * @param $subject
     * @param $result
     * @return string
     * @throws NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function afterGetJsonConfigurationHtmlEscaped($subject, $result): string
    {
        $resultData = $result;
        if($categoryUrl = $this->getCategoryUrl()) {
            $data = $this->jsonSerializer->unserialize($result);
            if (is_array($data) && key_exists('breadcrumbs',$data)) {
                $data['breadcrumbs']['alternativeReferrer'] = trim($categoryUrl);
                $resultData = $this->jsonSerializer->serialize($data);
            }
        }

        return $resultData;
    }

    /**
     * @return false
     * @throws NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function getCategoryUrl()
    {
        $categoryUrl = false;
        if ($category = $this->getDipperCategory()) {
            $categoryUrl = $category->getUrl();
        }

        return $categoryUrl;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     * @throws NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function getDipperCategory()
    {
        $currentProduct = $this->getProduct();
        $categoryCollection = clone $currentProduct->getCategoryCollection();
        $categoryCollection->clear();
        $categoryCollection->addAttributeToSort('level', $categoryCollection::SORT_ORDER_DESC)
            ->addAttributeToFilter('path', array('like' => "1/" . $this->storeManager->getStore()->getRootCategoryId() . "/%"));
        $categoryCollection->setPageSize(1);
        $dipperCategory = $categoryCollection->getFirstItem();

        return $dipperCategory;
    }

    /**
     * @return ProductInterface
     * @throws NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function getProduct(): ProductInterface
    {
        if (!isset($this->currentProduct)) {
            $productId = $this->getProductId();

            if ($productId) {
                $this->currentProduct = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);
            }
        }
        return $this->currentProduct;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getProductId(): string
    {
        return $this->catalogSession->getData('last_viewed_product_id');
    }
}
```

2. Need or add file to theme Or make mixin

Magento_Catalog::js/product/breadcrumbs.js

change Options section

```
 options: {
                categoryUrlSuffix: '',
                useCategoryPathInUrl: false,
                product: '',
                categoryItemSelector: '.category-item',
                menuContainer: '[data-action="navigation"] > ul',
                alternativeReferrer: 'alternativeReferrer'
            },
```

and
change function

```
 _resolveCategoryUrl: function () {
                var categoryUrl;
                var alternativeReferrer=this.options.alternativeReferrer;

                if (this.options.useCategoryPathInUrl) {
                    // In case category path is used in product url - resolve category url from current url.
                    categoryUrl = window.location.href.split('?')[0];
                    if (alternativeReferrer && alternativeReferrer.length > categoryUrl.length) {
                        categoryUrl = alternativeReferrer;
                        if (categoryUrl.indexOf('?') > 0) {
                            categoryUrl = categoryUrl.substr(0, categoryUrl.indexOf('?'));
                        }
                    } else {
                        categoryUrl = categoryUrl.substring(0, categoryUrl.lastIndexOf('/')) +
                            this.options.categoryUrlSuffix;
                    }
                } else {
                    // In other case - try to resolve it from referrer (without parameters).
                    categoryUrl = document.referrer;

                    if (categoryUrl.indexOf('?') > 0) {
                        categoryUrl = categoryUrl.substr(0, categoryUrl.indexOf('?'));
                    }
                }

                return categoryUrl;
            }
```